# Basic Idea about twitter type follow/Unfollow functionality in angular?

Tags: angular

Logged in any user and see list of one other users name and in front of name has one button Follow, after clicking follow button it toggles and change name as Unfollow after unfollow button again toggle and change with follow how to make this type of follow unfollow functionality in angular?

In database I have user table, i have to make new follow table(which column is required to make this), for follow which type query is required, for unfollow which type of query is required?

Answer (score 0):

```
//here is toggle button code 
//twitter-component.html

<style>
    .followup{
        color: red
    }

    .unfollow{
        color: green
    }
</style> 
<form>

<button [ngClass]="{'followup' : isFollow == true,
    'unfollow' : isFollow== false }" 
    (click)="onClick()">
    {{isFollow == true ? 'Unfollow' : (isFollow == false ? 'Follow' : '')}}
</button>
</form>

//twitter-component.ts

export class TwitterComponent implements OnInit {

  public isFollow: boolean = false;
  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onClick(){
    this.isFollow = !this.isFollow;

  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of posting a new answer, please edit your first answer and add all your edits right there.

Answer (score -1):

Here is sample code, you can use your data values to check subscription and unsubscription.

```
//twitter-component.ts

import { TestDataServiceService } from '../services/twitter-data-service.service';
export class TwitterComponent implements OnInit {

  public newTwitterPostDataToShowOnView: string

  constructor(private data: TestDataServiceService) { }

  followClick() {
    this.data.twitterPostedData.subscribe(postData =>
      this.newTwitterPostDataToShowOnView = postData);
  }

  unFollowClick() {
    this.data.newTwitterPostSource.unsubscribe()
  }
}

//twitter-data-service.service.ts 

import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable()
export class TwitterDataServiceService {
  //Behavior Subject is empty as there would be no default post initially
  private newTwitterPostSource = new BehaviorSubject("");
  twitterPostedData = this.newTwitterPostSource.asObservable();

  TwitterPostPublished(newTwitterPostData: string) {
    this.newTwitterPostSource.next(newTwitterPostData);
    //error method is optional
    this.newTwitterPostSource.error(err => console.log(err));
    //complete method is optional
    this.newTwitterPostSource.complete();
  }
}
```